# An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I have trouble building my project. There is no errors and i can deploy perfectly, the problem is i just cant build the project.

I am pretty sure there are no missing classes or libraries, and positively sure no compiler errors.

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:793)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:722)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1700(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1029)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1108)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:333)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found
E:\NetBeans Projects\test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:876: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\NetBeans Projects\test\nbproject\build-impl.xml:309: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

line 876 of build-impl is

```
    <webproject2:javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
```

line 309of build-impl is

```
    <javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}">
```

What am i missing here?

Using netbeans IDE 7.2.1 and this project is using JSF

Answer (score 1):

Seems like as per stack trace there is compilation error (javac executed via `Ant`):

There is custom class not found error:

```
class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found
```

You need to make sure in `build.xml` for `javac` target/task you are setting correct classpath, looks like bouncycastle jar/classes are missing in class path for `javac` target.

Edit: in your `Ant` javac target there is no classpath defined. see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html. You can use something like

```
<path id="javac.classpath">  
    <pathelement location="lib/"/>  
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>  
    <pathelement path="${additional.path}"/>  
 </path>  

<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" .. more attr ..>
    <classpath refid="javac.classpath/>
</javac>
```

Comment: hi, im kinda new to Ant, and i'm not sure where to start. i dont think im using a class file for `org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp` is there any way to know what is using this class?

Comment: @galao seems like your build.xml is netbeans specific, webproject2:javac points to http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/2, I don't know from where jar is being referred but suspecting on webproject2:javac. You can try adding bouncycastle jar from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html and see if it solves your issue